# Adding Feature IDs to existing MbTiles or on Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, tippecanoe

**Question TLDR:**

Is there a way to add feature IDs to an mbtiles file after it is generated?
Or alternatively: is there a way to add feature IDs to a source via mapbox either client side or otherwise?

**Details:**

I have a large geoJson dataset of over 20Gb that I exported to mbtiles with tippecanoe which took around 3 days in order to upload to Mapbox as a tileset.

Unfortunately I forgot to set the `--generate-ids` flag when exporting, so my features have no feature ids and therefore do not have the functionality I require on mapbox (setFeatureState on particular features).

Is it possible to add in featureIds after the fact to mbtiles files?  On the mapbox side I am aware of both `generateId` (unfortunately geojson specific) and `promoteId` [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#vector-promoteId) which I **could** use with my data but unfortunately does not work because the source is being created with a URL and gives the error:

```
sources.<source-name>.promoteId: a source with a "url" property may not include a "promoteId" property
```

Otherwise, I will have to re-generate the entire mbtiles file which seems like a bit of a waste.